# Change website path deployed

Tags: websphere

My application is deployed on websphere; the url is something like `www.abc.com/xyz` The client wants it to just be `www.abc.com`.

I tried changing the index file in the admin console, but I can't find the index file for the default (`www.abc.com`) - How can I change the path?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the context root of the web module, not the index file.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the context root of the default application to a test page and that worked. However I also changed the root context of the application to just / but i am getting a 404 error. What else should I do? or did I miss anything? I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the potential solutions is to go to admin console (click `Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > application_name > Context root for web modules`) and change context root for your web module as described [Context root for web modules settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/uweb_contextroot.html).

If you have default installation, make sure you first change the root context for the `DefaultApplication` if it exists, as it has same context root (`/`).

Comment: Thank you! I changed the context root of the default application to a test page and that worked. However I also changed the root context of the application to just / but i am getting error. What else should I do?

Comment: @Aida If you are using web server with plugin, you will need to regenerate and propagate plugin configuration file.